# Stereo to surround mixing software advice

Tags: stereo-to-surround, conversion, upmixing, surround-sound, broadcasting

Is anyone out there familiar with stereo-to-surround (upmixing) software like [Waves UM226](https://www.waves.com/plugins/um225-um226) or [TC Electronics Unwrap](http://www.tcelectronic.com/UnwrapTDM.asp) and the Broadcasters' ([Discovery](https://dplay.nl/discovery/) or [National Geographic](https://natgeotv.com/)) acceptance/knowledge therein?

Thx much

[image: Waves UM226]
<sub>(source: [waves.com](http://www.waves.com/objects/Images/Screenshots/um226_sshot_small.jpg))</sub>

Comment: J. Martin, I'm also downvoting this question as it doesn't really pertain to the topic of sound design. Are you trying to use said software to design a sound or is this more of a technical question? (If design related, I'm happy to remove my negative vote.)

Comment: Just googled "TC Tools Unwrap", so do you mean plugins to convert from stereo to surround? Sorry if I'm not getting your question. Would you like to give a bit more info?  

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this thread](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/434235-stereo-5-1-a.html) and [this thread](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/479388-upmix-plug-ins.html) at Gearslutz, which discuss upmix solutions.